# composer.json recursive dependencies

Tags: php, module, composer-php

I'm trying to manage my personal packages via Composer and I'm getting some errors when I  "composer update/install" a module (which depends on another module which depends on another module, etc).

I have a composer.json file in my Admin module which references and requires a personal repository "Access" :

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.[hidden].com:[hidden]/php-zf2-access.git"
        },
],
"require": {
        [hidden]/php-zf2-access": "dev-master"
}
```

My Access module has a composer.json file which references and requires a personal repository Basic :

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.[hidden].com:[hidden]/php-zf2-basic.git"
        }
    ],
"require": {
        "[hidden]/php-zf2-basic": "dev-master"
    },
```

When I'm installing/updating my Admin module, I get this error :

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> ```
> - Installation request for [hidden]/php-zf2-access dev-master -> satisfiable by [hidden]/php-zf2-access[dev-master].
>
> - [hidden]/php-zf2-access dev-master requires [hidden]/php-zf2-basic dev-master -> no matching package found.
> ```

If I "composer install" my Access module, it correctly loads my Basic module (no configuration error in my composer.json Access module), so why my Admin module can't load Access which loads Basic ?

If I add my Basic module configuration (repositories : ....basic.git + require: .....basic:"dev-master") to my composer.json's Admin module, no error is raised and the installation runs perfectly (but I don't want this as a solution).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Composer [can not load repositories recursively](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md). The easiest if you have private packages to manage that have dependencies on each other is to use [Toran Proxy](https://toranproxy.com/) or [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis).